# Mongo shell not creating indexes on running databases

Tags: mongodb

We dumped the definition of indexes using `mongo-index-exporter` and we try to apply them at each launch of our application, so to achieve a reproducible environment, by executing

```
mongo --verbose "mongodb://$MONGO_DB_USER:$MONGO_DB_PASSWORD@$MONGO_DB_HOST/$MONGO_DB_NAME?authSource=$MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE&authMode=scram-sha1" indexes.js
```

on a file like so:

```
print('Using db ' + db)
setVerboseShell(true)
print('Creating indexes on mycoll1')
db.mycoll1.createIndex({"_id":1}, {"name":"_id_", "background": true});
db.mycoll1.createIndex({"createdAt":1,"field1.field2.field3":1}, {"name":"coll1_field123_idx"});
print('Creating indexes on mycoll2')
db.mycoll2.createIndex({"_id":1}, {"name":"_id_", "background": true});
db.mycoll2.createIndex({"createdAt":1,"field1.field2.field3":1}, {"name":"coll1_field123_idx"});
```

To create indexes on a replicaSet with five nodes, we are performing the 
following command:

```
mongo --verbose "mongodb://$MONGO_DB_USER:$MONGO_DB_PASSWORD@$MONGO_DB_HOST/$MONGO_DB_NAME?authSource=$MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE&authMode=scram-sha1" indexes.js
```

this works fine for us in QA, where MONGO_DB_HOST is a single node and we are using a fresh new empty database, and doesn't work in production where additionally the database is already existing (and the collection have contents).

Additional relevant information:

1. background mode doesn't make any difference
2. The verbose mode doesn't work, i.e. although we launch mongo client with -v and we do a setVerbose(true) nothing is logged on the console
3. Our mongo shell is 3.6.11 and our mongo server is 3.2.9
4. Copy pastying the commands inside a mongo shell executed on the server works terminates immediately and results in the following output

   {
       "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
       "numIndexesBefore" : 11,
       "numIndexesAfter" : 11,
       "note" : "all indexes already exist",
       "ok" : 1
   }

Comment: The db already has all 11 indexes. There are no new indexes to create.

Comment: We know that the database has already all the indexes, so we expected the script to be executed blazing fast and nothing to happen. Instead, what happens is that mongo client hangs

Comment: Does it hang? Any output? "doesn't work" is quite vague.

Comment: It happened to me once. I did use `db.collectionName.reIndex()` to create indexes for existing documents.

Comment: It does hang, nothing happens at all . @ViharManchala I do not want to create indexes, they already exists